# Pandas resample function not working on DateTimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame called `aus` that looks like this:

```
+--------------+-------------+
|              | link clicks |
+--------------+-------------+
| created_time |             |
| 2015-07-20   |        8600 |
| 2015-07-21   |       11567 |
| 2015-07-22   |        1809 |
| 2015-07-23   |        7032 |
| 2015-07-26   |       23704 |
+--------------+-------------+
```

I make the index a DateTimeIndex like so:
`aus.index = pd.to_datetime(aus.index)`

Then I run a check like this: `type(aus.index)` and the given output is `pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex`

Then when I try to resample the index into weeks like so 
`aus.index = aus.resample('w', how='sum', axis=1)` I am met with the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-310-3268a3f46a19> in <module>()
----> 1 aus.index = aus.resample('w', how='sum', axis=1)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in resample(self, rule, how, axis, fill_method, closed, label, convention, kind, loffset, limit, base)
   3264                               fill_method=fill_method, convention=convention,
   3265                               limit=limit, base=base)
-> 3266         return sampler.resample(self).__finalize__(self)
   3267 
   3268     def first(self, offset):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/resample.pyc in resample(self, obj)
    100             return self.obj
    101         else:  # pragma: no cover
--> 102             raise TypeError('Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex')
    103 
    104         rs_axis = rs._get_axis(self.axis)

TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex
```

My type check earlier says I have the proper index, but the resample function doesn't thinks so.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

axis=1 means it's trying to resample the columns (which isn't a DatetimeIndex).

```
In [11]: df.columns
Out[11]: Index([u'link clicks'], dtype='object')

In [12]: type(df.columns)
Out[12]: pandas.core.index.Index
```

Use axis=0:

```
In [21]: aus.resample('w', how='sum', axis=0)
Out[21]:
              link clicks
created_time
2015-07-26          52712
```

Note: this is the default for resample:

```
In [22]: aus.resample('w', how='sum')
Out[22]:
              link clicks
created_time
2015-07-26          52712
```

Comment: @meter Could you pastebin/something a reproducible example ? I'm not sure what would give you that off-hand.

Comment: Figured the issue out. Something stupid on my part.  Thanks for this answer, I was scratching my head for an hour.